How to fix Firestore CORS issues only appearing on reload
I have an application created with React/Next and Firebase, using Firestore for document storage. This is a simple application with only three pages, that takes in travel details from the user (on the "Report") page, and then displays these in a table (on the "Overview" page). These two pages are the only ones actually fetching data from Firestore, and are single pages that upon navigation renders like myUrl.com/overview in the URL, if this is of any importance.
When I was only working in localhost, I got this error:
    Fetch API cannot load **** due to access control checks.

If you have worked with Firebase/Firestore before, you probably know that this error has been discussed up and down in Github issues, with the developers saying to just ignore this error. So, that's what I did. However, when uploading it to a hosting service (AWS S3 with CloudFront), this started to become an actual issue. When loading the documents on initial load, all the data displays as it should. I am also able to switch between pages. However, if refreshing one of these two pages that actually fetch user travel data from Firestore, I get the console error mentioned above (in addition to a 403) and the entire application crashes, with an XML error being displayed in the browser. It says 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
' and tells me Access Denied, if this is of any importance.
I am at my wits end, and don't know how to fix this problem, so any help would be much appreciated. I have done a lot of googling and it seems to be some type of CORS issue.
I believe this type of Firestore interaction in the code is what causes the CORS issues (the getData function is being called in useEffect), without knowing how to fix it.
const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await getJourneys()
            const journeys: any = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            }))
            setJourneys(journeys)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    const getJourneys = async () => {
        const journeyCollection = collection(db, 'users', user?.uid, 'journeys')
        const journeySnap = await getDocs(journeyCollection)
        return journeySnap
    }

I have tried rewriting the application to a SPA, to see if it helps to not have the /overview extension in the browser, but this does not seem to work either.
I have seen other suggestions online of adding a cors.json file and using the google cloud cli, but as I am not using Cloud Storage or Cloud Functions (that I know of), this has not worked out for me.
What confuses me is that the entire thing works just as it should, until I refresh the page. Not sure if I can add some delays to the useEffect functions in order to fix this, but while I have attempted this it does not seem to work. I would greatly appreciate ANY tips/feedback you guys have regarding this issue.
